# How to Include Soft Skill Activities

Tags: resume, skills, non-work-activities

I’m a software developer and I’m looking to update my resume with some “soft skill activities” that I have done within the past few years. For instance, I started swimming with a local masters team. It’s a volunteer organization with multiple sites and after about a year they asked me to help them coach. I’ve been doing that for a while and I think it has definitely helped with my people skills. In addition, I recently started taking an improv class which has also helped with my people skills.

My question is, what’s the most appropriate place to put information for “soft skill activities”? Do I put both under a miscellaneous umbrella section or put them in different sections?

Comment: Recruiters and hiring positions scam over many resumes. Overall consider placing outstanding information. You could title your contribution as Community Service or NGO Contribution, Volunteering, or anything that highlights the value that you want to highlight. It‘s not only a matter of doing sport or social skills, it is that you are doing it in the best possible way with others that agree that you are very useful and call you in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put mine at the bottom under a small section titled "Interests".

I mention about 5 or 6 pastimes I find interesting and I try to keep it broad (ie a couple of sports I do, some musical instruments I play and a couple of hobbies). It has been useful in interviews from time to time as an ice breaker.

Here's what I have:

> INTERESTS
>   Fitness | Traveling | Tennis | Sailing | Krav Maga (Martial Arts) | Music (Playing Piano and Drums)

I once applied for a job where the manager and seniors loved to play tennis once a week, as you can imagine my resume did stand out.  I got an interview but not the job.

Another application I made the manager was apparently a jiu-jitsu instructor in his spare time.  Having krav maga in my interests made me stand out and I did get the job (along with an invite to come along to his classes after work).

You never know, your interests are who you are. Some people pay attention to them, some don't.  No harm in having them there.

Comment: +1 and, I confirm that, as a recruiter, this is a section I pay attention to and gets to my memory. It helps remembering each candidate as a unique person.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, what’s the most appropriate place to put information for “soft skill activities”?

Near the end/bottom - put your 'job related' stuff early; at or near the top.

> Do I put both under a miscellaneous umbrella section or put them in different sections?

I'm not sure it matters how you title or format it, but make it very brief - they'll ask if they care to know more.
Some people care about that kind of stuff and some don't, I don't believe you will harm your chances for a job by having them at the end of your resume.

A former boss of mind swore that the reason he got a job at IBM Canada straight out of school was because of a hobby he put on his resume. If he was telling the truth they never asked him technical stuff (more understandable because he was a new grad / first job).

Answer (score 0):

You could list them as hobbies but I wouldn't recommend that.  It's unlikely that interviewers are going to spend a lot of time looking at those sorts of things on a resume and they're unlikely to connect the dots between an improv class and something that makes you more qualified for the job.

On the other hand, if these activities are improving your people skills, you can connect the dots for the interviewer by showing in your description of what you did how you utilized soft skills.  If coaching swimming gave you skills that you used to mentor junior developers better, describe that in your resume.  If improv helped you get buy-in from senior leadership to rewrite some process, describe that in your resume.